# Message: 'chromedriver_win32.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to using Selenium. However, I am getting an error like this at the beginning. I tried the solutions found on the site but I still get the same error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver_path = (r"C:\Users\win10\Desktop\Test\chromedriver_win32.exe")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
```

Error Message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_win32.exe' executable 
needs to be in PATH.
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the chromedriver_win32.exe is not found in your path. You can add the chrome driver to a directory which is already exist in the path.
you can replace driver path by the below line to find absolute path.

driver_path = os.path.abspath("chromedriver_win32.exe")

Please make sure you have the chrome driver in your system if the above step doesn't work then  most likely the name of the executable must be different.

Comment: When I run driver_path before typing the "browser" line, the chrome tab opens. Doesn't that mean you have the chrome driver?

Comment: You can check by issuing chromedriver.exe -v in command prompt to verify whether its properly added in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = 'https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=arush")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\Arush\Python\chromedriver.exe', options = chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
driver.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features = 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Change the values of url and executable_path accordingly.
I'll attach the chromedriver v2.34 which is compatible with Google Chrome v63.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cyXu4VsuGuhUXoHJssjzxCI4Nt9tHEah/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.